# Component source for the Mac world

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Do you know of any source of paid code components or library for XCode and the Objective-C language like [Component Source](http://www.componentsource.com/index.html) ?
It's a website for paid libraries of code that you can use in your project. In the past, when my team was working on a C# project I used two of them, DevExpress and GraphicsMill: We found them really useful. Now I'm starting an XCode project and I'd like to know if anything like this is already available.

Comment: this question is better suited to our sister site, Stack Overflow.  it will be migrated shortly.  you seem to already have an account there, so I've associated it with your Super User account so that your SO account will automatically regain ownership of the question.

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation on what "Component Source" is?  Is it plugins for your IDE that add functionality to the editor itself?  Is it libraries of code that you can use in your project?  Their website looks like a giant adwords page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifically looking to pay for libraries?  If you are, then I don't know of many sites that explicitly *sell* libraries (but you're always welcome to send me money if you REALLY want to pay *someone* :D ).

Most of the libraries that I know of, use, and love are open source.  They're all over the place; there's no "central repository" of Cocoa libraries.  There are some really awesome libraries on Github, Google Code, BitBucket, and SourceForge.  Then there are other libraries that are privately hosted, like OGREKit, CHDataStructures, etc.

If you could give specific examples of functionality you're looking for, we can be much more helpful.